# Image not shown after setImageBitmap

Tags: onactivityresult

I'm doing an android project in which I need to let the user to take a picture and out it as a profile picture
I'm not sure what's wrong but the image is not shown after it's taken.

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)  {
if (requestCode == ACTIVITY_START_CAMERA_APP && resultCode == RESULT_OK) 
 {
        Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("date");
        profilePicture.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
        wasPhoto = true;
        Toast.makeText(this, "Profile Picture taken successfully", 
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}


<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/IVAddPicture"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:src="@drawable/person_image" />
```

[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3qVHk.png)

[After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SMIyg.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code in your onActivityResult

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

                super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

                if (requestCode == ACTIVITY_START_CAMERA_APP && resultCode == RESULT_OK
                        && null != data) {

                    try {

                        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();

                        Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(mActivity.getContentResolver(), selectedImage);
                        profilePicture.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } 
            }
```